# Is there any way to run same cucumber feature file multiple times?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I have some documents to upload it. For that, I wrote a scenario. I need to run the same feature file multiple times. How can I run the feature file Multiple times?

Comment: Can you post the feature file you have so far?

Comment: Is it the documents you see having a problem with?

Comment: You could create multiple runners?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using multiple feature file use scenario outline which will execute the same scenario multiple time as per the example table you will provide to it

Example:

```
Scenario Outline: Create ABC

  Given I open the application

  When I enter username as <username>

  And I enter password as <password>

  Then I enter title as <title>

  And press submit


Examples:

| username | password | title |

| Rob      | xyz1      | title1 |

| Bob      | xyz1      | title2 |
```

So here the same scenario will run 2 times as example table have 2 data, you can add as many data table and cucumber will execute that number of times